# How can I build the regex to match a string NOT containing "au=1"?

Tags: regex, .htaccess

As the title says... :)

Could you help me to build a regex to match a strings NOT containing "au=1"?

I was playing with negative lookahead with no luck but I'm quite sure that I should get something using that.

Thanks!

Comment: it will be used on a .htaccess rewriting rule (isapirewrite)

Comment: I don't think .htaccess regular expressions support lookahed/lookbehind.

Comment: According what I see on the documentation, this is permitted: "Sometimes you need to apply rule when some pattern not matches. In this case you may use so called Forward Lookahead Asserts in regular expressions."

Comment: But no mention of lookbehind. See my new answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally did it with this regexp

```
^(?!.*au=1).*$
```

Answer (score 1):

Using negative lookbehind:

```
?<!au=1
```

Negative lookahead will only look *ahead*, making the regex `match` match against `au=1match`. You should read up on the differences in more detail [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'm testing your regex on "Expresso" but it match absolutely nothing :( I tested different texts and nothing match

Answer (score 1):

You can also just match against `au=1` and negate the result:

```
if(!Regex.IsMatch(input, @"au=1"))
{
    //  blah blah blah
}
```

Comment: +1 but this is not what I need. My fault for adding C# wrongly. This regex will be used on a rewriting tool, there is no c# code.

Answer (score 1):

Prefix the pattern with `!` to negate it:

```
!au=1
```

Comment: +1 but fortunately, already solved it in a different way. Thanks!