# Is there a shorter way of writing this RegEx?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I have a regex that looks if the file extension of a file is not one of the given extensions. Is there a way I can write this without having to put the . in front of every extension?

```
^.*(?<!\.php|\.html|\.xml|\.js|\.css|\.bmp|\.ico|\.jpg|\.jpeg|\.png|\.gif|\.rss)$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can make use of a non-capture group:

```
^.*(?<!\.(?:php|html|xml|js|css|bmp|ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|rss)$)$
```

Though it's good too to use some character classes, maybe something like that:

```
^.*(?<!\.(?:(?:ht|x)ml|j(?:pg|s|peg)|p(?:hp|ng)|[rc]ss|bmp|ico|gif)$)$
```

This reduces the processing time. Though these are not exactly working because lookbehinds have to be fixed width in PHP, as such, I would advise using a negative lookahead as below:

```
^(?!.*\.(?:(?:ht|x)ml|j(?:peg|s|pg)|p(?:hp|ng)|[rc]ss|bmp|ico|gif)$).*$
```

Initial regex takes [120 steps](http://regex101.com/r/cG6cE4) to match, but only [35 steps](http://regex101.com/r/jH9yQ7) with the changes applied in the last regex.

If you want to match extensions such as `.phpx` however, you can use this:

```
^(?!.*\.(?:(?:ht|x)ml|j(?:peg|s|pg)|p(?:hp|ng)|[rc]ss|bmp|ico|gif)).*$
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to match any strings, it should for example still match test.rar but not test.php

Comment: @CupOfTea696 I was putting another regex inside, sorry about that.

Comment: Actually, this still matches test.phpx, but that can easily be prevented using ^(?!.*\.(?:(?:ht|x)ml|j(?:peg|s|pg)|p(?:hp|ng)|[rc]ss|bmp|ico|gif)$).*$

Comment: @CupOfTea696 Yea, I didn't realise that when changing the method, the position of the anchor would have to be changed as well. :)

Comment: Strange things is that this works perfectly in RegExr, but it doesn't work when I use it in my .htaccess

Comment: @CupOfTea696 Hmm, I'm not sure... As per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4564902/1578604) question, this format should be working. Or maybe the regex is a bit complex for .htaccess? :( Though I think that on the opposite, it's simpler for the engine, oh well. Thanks for accepting my answer :)

Comment: Tbh the first regex I had didn't work in .htaccess either. It did work when i only did a ./ in front of the php but of course it would only work as it should for php files and not for any of the others.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can use:

```
^.*(?<!\.(?:php|html|xml|js|css|bmp|ico|jpe?g|png|gif|.rss)$)$
```

Move dot outside the group since it is common to all extension and `jpg|jpeg` can b written as `jpe?g`